# Is it possible to stop page loading on the browser using selenium web-driver?

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, ruby

I searched online, but couldn't find anything about how to stop page loading over a browser using `selenium web-driver`.

Any idea for the same?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'stop page loading' ?

Comment: he wants the page to stop loading...

Answer (score 11):

This might be useful.

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys("Keys.ESCAPE");
```

OR

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("return window.stop");
```

You must use `driver.page_load_strategy = 'none'` if using chrome else chromedriver will wait for full url to load before performing execution

Comment: The find element body did not work for me as it could not find the element until the page loaded. However the Javascript works beautifully

Answer (score 5):

If you want to simulate the browser's STOP button, this post should help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453423/how-to-stop-the-page-loading-in-firefox-programaticaly

Comment: yeah! I have gone through that post earlier,but couldn't understand how to really write it... as that was shorthand code. can you help me on that?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using firefox then you can set preference for default timeout:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("http.response.timeout", 5)
fp.set_preference("dom.max_script_run_time", 5)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

driver.get("http://www.google.com/")
```

This will stop page load after 5 seconds.

Comment: I get: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dom.max_script_run_time must be == 0 || >= 30`
So, minimum is 30 seconds or 0.

Answer (score 3):

There were a few possible solutions to this over on Stackoverflow on [Stop browser load from selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15834158/175051).

This included:

- [Installing an extension in Chrome called Stop load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15840935/175051)
- [using the built in pageLoadTimeout() method in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15835719/175051)
- [using Sikuli or Autoit to access the browser's native controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15835719/175051)

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a function you may call](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout) to set the page load timeout you need.

Comment: Link only answers are not encouraged. Please add the solution part of the link to your answer.

Comment: Also, the link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I use three steps with chrome and it works:

1. Navigate to "about:blank"
2. Get element "body"
3. On that element send keys "Esc"

Answer (score 0):

We can use `windows.stop();` in order to stop the page loading. Try the below code:

```
driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.execute_script()` method didn't work for me as it turned out the specified script was executing on an `about:blank` page before it visited the url. What *did* work for me was injecting the script into the chromedriver session itself (such that the script runs for every page load) inspired from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68621383/21489337).

```py
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument', {'source': 'setTimeout(function(){window.stop();}, 5000);'})
driver.get(urls)
```