# How can we move to next action immediately after calling webDriver.get() method without waiting for page to change to ready state

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, timeout

I am automating few test cases on a webpage, but the problem is when this page opens it takes 10-15 seconds to come to ready state. So when I call webDriver.get() method, it waits until page state becomes ready and doesn't perform next action on a link which was available 10 seconds earlier.

Can anyone suggest how to avoid this wait which is inside webdriver's get function so that after calling get() methods I can add my explicit wait until the element appears (which generally appears in 1-2 seconds) and can move to next steps since I don't bother about the ready state of my current page.

Comment: May be there could be some ugly solution like 1 - before you load the page you override the timeout for loading the page setting it to some rather small value. 2 - you wrap the getUrl with tryCatch where you ignore the exception, 3 - you try to access element on the page after excveption is thrown, 4 - you restore the original value of timeout. However this is just a guess, not sure this will work.

Answer (score 1):

For `get()` function the sequence will complete first action(open webpage) and wait till page is ready and if the next action is ready, for example element is present and no use for explicit wait or sleep , it will go for it directly and so on

Try : `driver.navigate().gotourl("URL")` , also it allow some features like forward, back

Comment: fine, but I don't want it to wait until the page is ready because page becomes ready too late and the element on which I want to perform the action is already there.

Comment: trythis: driver.navigate().GoToUrl("URL") instead of get() because get() wait for your page to load

Comment: It will not always work, because many times page loads because of clicking on some link.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the PageLoadStrategy capability to none when you create your driver instance, I use this when using Chrome to get around the issue where it times out after 30 seconds.  Sometimes the page has not completely loaded but elements are there etc but the page is not in a ready state so it just sits there and does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try simulating the browser stop action that a User would do when the page keeps loading.I use this for one of my test scenarios.
Try:

```
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;<br/>
   js.executeScript("return window.stop");
```

Also you can refer to the below threads:

- [Is it possible to stop page loading on the browser using selenium web-driver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/is-it-possible-to-stop-page-loading-on-the-browser-using-selenium-web-driver)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453423/how-to-stop-the-page-loading-in-firefox-programmatically