# How do I get the disabled state of a Submit button after click, but before page reload?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, page-objects

The code I am attempting to test prevents double submitting of a form by detecting the click event via Javascript and disabling the button.

To clarify, the sequence of events is as follows:

- Navigate to the requisite page
- Find the button in page
- Click the button
- Button gets disabled via Javascript
- Form is submitted

My test code (as pseudo code) is as follows:

```
final Page page = getPage();
final WebElement button = page.getButton();
button.click();
Assert.assertFalse(button.isEnabled(), "Button still enabled");
```

The button is actually a div with an attached onClick handler, which looks like this:

```
-- Before Click
<div id="button" onclick="..." class="action-button">
    <i class="fa fa-play"></i> Run
</div>

-- After Click
<div id="button" class="action-button" disabled="disabled">
    <i class="fa fa-play"></i> Run
</div>
```

The actual submit button itself is hidden for reasons I can't change, so when the user clicks on the div I've documented, the onClick event actually calls the hidden submit button's click event and also sets the div to disabled and removes the onClick handler.

It seems as though the .click() event is blocking until the page reloads, which means by the time the assert is executed the button object is no longer referenced, and I can't check the state.

Is there a way to assert something on the button before the page reloads?

Comment: Please add the html of button state before n after click

Comment: I added some more details. Cheers!

Comment: if the button is not referenced how you wer able to get the html after the click manually?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? I am able to reference the div, which is the thing in the DOM that gets disabled, but once I call .click() on the div the test blocks until the page loads completely and I'm unable to check the disabled state, as the page reload resets the div's disabled state.

Comment: What i meant is , on clicking the button the page starts to reload. So how did you able to see the state after the click ?

Comment: Oh, right, I visually verified during a manual test by using Chrome Developer tools to view the page source dynamically change when I clicked the button.

Comment: do you have website link to try this on ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491608/selenium-test-disable-on-submit-behavior

Comment: I don't have a site, sorry. I have also tried that solution, but it also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/is-it-possible-to-stop-page-loading-on-the-browser-using-selenium-web-driver

Comment: Why not test this at a lower level? Unit tests wouldn't have the page reloading problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this feature is legacy and there's no scope to unit test this piece of code. The hope was to build automated tests to handle regression during refactoring.

As for the proposed solutions at https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/is-it-possible-to-stop-page-loading-on-the-browser-using-selenium-web-driver, they also don't seem to work. The sticking factor is the .click() event blocking.

Answer (score 1):

**The below code works for the test HTML shown**:

```
Boolean return_value = (Boolean) js.executeScript("arguments[0].click(); return arguments[1].disabled;",  button1,button2);
Assert.assertTrue(return_value, "Button still enabled");
```

Were, button 1 is the "Try it" button, and button 2 is the "My button"

**The html I used for testing:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button id="myBtn">My Button</button>

<p>Click the button below to disable the button above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction();window.location.reload();">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**So for your SUT , the code will be**:

```
Boolean return_value = (Boolean) js.executeScript("arguments[0].click(); return arguments[0].disabled;",  button);

Assert.assertTrue(return_value, "Button still enabled");
```

**Try wait: if above doesn't work**

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));

 wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd ->
    (Boolean) js.executeScript("arguments[0].click(); return 
       arguments[0].disabled;",  button));
```

Comment: After a few goes in different configurations, including attempting to override the submit action in the executed Javascript before clicking, it looks that my particular sequence of events doesn't work with this solution either. I can see how it should work, but I can't seem to get it to execute correctly.

Comment: @MankyFox what error are you getting ?

Comment: Try with executeasyncscript

Comment: I'm actually getting a response, but it's null, signalling to me that it's still getting the disabled state after the submit has complete. I've done some contrived tests on returning the id instead, and I get that back fine, so I know the Javascript is actually executing. I'll try the Async method and see how I go.

Comment: @MankyFox `             `Boolean return_value = (Boolean)js.executeAsyncScript("var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];"+
              "arguments[0].click;"+
               "while(1){"
               + "if(arguments[1].disabled){"
               + "callback(arguments[0].disabled)}}",button);` try this one ?

Comment: @MankyFox try using the wait as I mentioned in the updated answer

Comment: It actually looks to cause the page to hang, which I think means the loop break condition never hits. I've actually found another way to complete the test, where I fire a Javascript event to disable the submit action on the button click and then test for the button being disabled regardless. It's less than ideal, but I guess it tests the effect I intend. I think I'm going to sit on it for now. Thank you for you assistance!